# " Cannot GET / " error in Node.js

Tags: html, node.js

I am using Node.js to run a simple HTML server. The index.js file boots perfectly fine, but its where you connect is when you see a problem. Whenever you do connect you see `Cannot GET /` plastered all over the site, nothing else.

```
//Vars
var http       = require('http');
var express    = require("express");
var app        = express();
var connect    = require("connect");

//Show .html file

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//Port to listen to

app.listen(8080);

//Just for show

const PORT = 8080;
console.log("Server listening on: http://***.***.***.**:%s", PORT);
```

That is the code I am using for index.js, I hope someone can find my problem and help me fix it. Thanks. (Sorry if this question has been asked by other people)

Comment: What's in your `/public` directory?

Comment: Are you not missing `app.get('/',function(req, res){..........})` ?

Comment: @Jacob There is the file `index/index.html` and `refused/refused.html`. I have personally tried to change the defined directory in index.js to the`/public/index/index.html` file, but only results in another `Cannot GET /` error.

Comment: I believe that `/` will look for an `index.html` file _in the static directories_. The fact that you have `/index/index.html` instead if `/index.html` probably means that it can't find the default document for `/`.

Comment: @Fabio I have gotten rid of that line a long time ago, I think it was a node I installed.

Comment: @Jacob Thanks, it solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the index.html file in the wrong place, had to move it to the default directory for `/public`. Which is in the root of `/public`.